# define $f :R\to R$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)}$ when $x<1$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{(x-1)}$ when $x\geq 1$. Show that $f$ is a bijection and determine its inverse

Tags: functions

A bonus Q on a discrete math/proofs test, I know I must prove injectivity and surjectivity, but am not exactly sure how to do so. Please help, this will be covered on the upcoming final exam in April. Can somebody help me get started on this question?

Comment: You seem to be talking about a problem, but I don't see any problem in the question's body.

Answer (score 0):

First, the pieces defining $f$ are clearly injective (one is strictly decreasing on its domain, the other strictly increasing on its domain) and $f(x) = f(y)$ never happens for $x < 1 \leq y$ since $f$ is negative on $(-\infty,-1)$ and non-negative on $[1,\infty)$. So $f$ is injective.

Now, for $y \in \mathbb{R}$ consider two cases:

1. $y < 1$: 
   Then define $x = 1 + \frac{1}{y} < 1$, and note that $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+1/y)-1} = y$.
2. $y \geq 1$:
   Then define $x = y^2 + 1 \geq 1$. Then $f(x) = y$. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.